# Arrangement of items in HStack from left to right in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

For my current SwiftUI project, I need to roll my own time pickers, and I want to put three or four ordinary Pickers one after the other in order to let the user choose hours, minutes, seconds, and (locale requiring) AM/PM (and variations on this which are unimportant to my question).  My first thought on this is to put the pickers in an HStack.  E.g.,

```
HStack {
    Text("H")
    Text("M")
    Text("S")
}
```

(And, yes, the Text views are just placeholders.)  One problem:  HStack orders everything from leading to trailing.  For right-to-left languages, this is a problem, since this would result in the pickers being in the wrong order (S M H rather than H M S).  How can I force the order  items in an HStack to always be from left to right?

Note:  I did think of the flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(_:) view modifier, but trying to use this flipped over text, which is definitely not what I want.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: If the answer worked, you should click the check mark to accept it

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to fix layout direction by explicit environment value

```
HStack {
    Text("H")
    Text("M")
    Text("S")
}.environment(\.layoutDirection, .leftToRight)
```